# R error in '[<-.data.frame'... replacement has # items, need #

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and this one is beyond me. The script below uses two dummy tables (result and count) each with two columns (A and B). I'm running permutations tests to compare the results from A and B. Specifically, I'm looking at result/count for A and B. Both result and count have 20 rows and I've written a loop to run a permutation test for the first 10 rows of each, then the first 11, then 12, up to 20. When it works, which it does on occasion, I get a pretty graph at the end.

```
#Set up the dummy data - two competing tables (result & count)
result <- data.frame(matrix(runif(40)*100, nrow=20))
names(result)[1] <- paste("A"); names(result)[2] <- paste("B")
count <- data.frame(matrix(runif(40)*100, nrow=20))
names(count)[1] <- paste("A"); names(count)[2] <- paste("B")
n.iter <- 1e3

#Run a permutation test
permtest <- function(result, count) {
    n <- dim(result)[1]
#   print(n)
    stat <- function(x, y) abs(diff(range(colSums(x)/colSums(y))))
    swap <- function(x, i) { x[i, ] <- cbind(x[, "B"], x[, "A"])[i, ]; return (x) }
    sim <- replicate(n.iter, { i <- runif(n) < 1/2; stat(swap(result, i), swap(count, i)) })
    result.stat <- stat(result, count)
    p.value <- sum(sim >= result.stat) / length(sim)
    return(list(sim, result.stat, p.value))
}

#Compute evolution of p-values over time
p.evol <- data.frame()
for (i in 10:dim(result)[1]) {
#   print(i)
    permresults <- permtest(result[1:i,], count[1:i,])
    p.value <- permresults[[3]]
    p.evol <- rbind(p.evol, c(i, p.value, 1-p.value))
}
colnames(p.evol) <- c("day", "p.value", "conf")
dev.new()
plot(p.evol[,1],p.evol[,3], type="b", xlab="Day",ylab="Percentage", main="Evolution of Confidence")
```

The problem is that while sometimes it runs no problem, most of the time I get `Error in '[<-.data.frame'('*tmp*', i, , value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 items, need 24`. With `options(error=traceback)` I get the output here, which I am not understanding:

```
f(ngettext(m, "replacement has %d item, need %d", 
        "replacement has %d items, need %d"), m, n * p), domain = NA)
16: `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, , value = numeric(0)) at errortest.R#16
15: `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, , value = numeric(0)) at errortest.R#16
14: swap(result, i)
13: is.data.frame(x)
12: colSums(x)
11: diff(range(colSums(x)/colSums(y))) at errortest.R#15
10: stat(swap(result, i), swap(count, i)) at errortest.R#17
9: FUN(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)[[42L]], ...)
8: lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
7: sapply(integer(n), eval.parent(substitute(function(...) expr)), 
       simplify = simplify)
6: replicate(n.iter, {
       i <- runif(n) < 1/2
       stat(swap(result, i), swap(count, i))
   }) at errortest.R#17
5: permtest(result[1:i, ], count[1:i, ]) at errortest.R#27
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("errortest.R", echo = F)
```

What is particularly puzzling is that it works *sometimes*! How is this possible? I've also noticed that when I un-comment `print(n)` and `print(i)` it seems to make it work more frequently, although it can fail when they are not commented and work when they are. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This error pops up when you're unlucky and `i <- runif(n) < 1/2` consists only of `FALSE`, i.e. no permutations happen. You need to add a check in the `swap` function to fix this problem.

Comment: Wow. That's exactly it. How did you figure that out? Given that I'm running 1e3 iterations it seems to happen very frequently, so I guess I'm lucky when I *don't* get a row consisting of only 'FALSE'. I would have loved to aware extra points for the 'check' but I'm sure I can figure it out from here. ;-)

Comment: Traceback helped me to localize the problematic code, and I just put a bunch of prints around that place, so I knew the variable states when the error occurred. Here is the modified `swap` function: `swap <- function(x, i) { x[i, ] <- x[i, c(2,1)]; return (x) }` (it doesn't need a check when written in this way)

Comment: Sweet. I just wrote `swap <- function(x, i) { if(sum(i) != 0) { x[i, ] <- cbind(x[, "B"], x[, "A"])[i, ] }; return (x) }` but yours is, naturally, better. Bonus point awarded...