# R error in '[<-.data.frame 'C' *temp*',… replacement has # items, need #

Tags: r, function, runtime-error

I have a function that I've executed many times but is now throwing an error, which I do not understand. I'm trying to apply the function over a list.
I did not write the function and I have limited experience with functions. So, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the code.

**function:**

```
myfun<-function(Year, SampleID, Species, Abundance, resamps) {

  library(vegan)
  counter<-1
  simbaseline<-data.frame(array(NA,dim=c(length(unique(Year)),5)))
  names(simbaseline)<-c("Year", "Jaccard","Horn","Bray","Pearson")

  simnext<-data.frame(array(NA,dim=c(length(unique(Year)),5)))
  names(simnext)<-c("Year", "Jaccard","Horn","Bray","Pearson")

  simhind<-data.frame(array(NA,dim=c(length(unique(Year)),5)))
  names(simhind)<-c("Year", "Jaccard","Horn","Bray","Pearson")

  counter2<-1

  # getting vector with number of samples per year
  nsamples<-c()
  for(y in unique(Year)){
    nsamples<-c(nsamples, length(unique(SampleID[Year==y])))
  }
  t<-1
  minsample<-min(nsamples)
  for(repeats in 1:resamps){
    raref<-data.frame(array(NA,dim=c(1,3)))
    names(raref)<-c("Year","Species","Abundance")
    for(y in unique(Year)){
      #getting samples for this year
      samps<-unique(SampleID[Year==y])
      # re-sampling samples to equalize number of samples
      sam<-as.character(sample(samps,minsample,replace=T))
      # getting data that belongs to bootstraped samples
      rarefyear<-data.frame(SampleID[which(SampleID %in% sam & Year == y)],
                            Species[which(SampleID %in% sam & Year == y)],
                            Abundance[which(SampleID %in% sam & Year == y)])
      names(rarefyear)<-c("SampleID", "Species", "Abundance")
      # calculating pooled abundances of eahc species to store
      spabun<-tapply(as.numeric(rarefyear[,3]),rarefyear[,2],sum)
      spar<-data.frame(rep(y, length(spabun)),names(spabun),spabun, row.names=NULL)
      names(spar)<-c("Year","Species","Abundance")
      raref<-rbind(raref,spar)
      counter<-counter+1
    }
    # calculating year by species table of abundance
    rareftabtemp<-with(raref,tapply(Abundance,list(Year,Species),function(x)x))
    rareftabtemp[is.na(rareftabtemp)]<-0
    Pearsoncor<-cor(t(log(rareftabtemp+1)), method="pearson")
    # calculating between year similarities (NOT DISTANCE!) with Jaccard, Morisita-Horn, Bray and Pearson correlations
    Jacsim<-as.matrix(1-vegdist(rareftabtemp, method="jaccard"))
    Hornsim<-as.matrix(1-vegdist(rareftabtemp, method="horn"))
    Braysim<-as.matrix(1-vegdist(rareftabtemp, method="bray"))
    n<-length(unique(Year))
    simbaseline[counter2:(counter2+n-2),]<-
         cbind(unique(Year)[2:n],Jacsim[2:n],Hornsim[2:n],Braysim[2:n],Pearsoncor[2:n])
    simnext[counter2:(counter2+n-2),]<-
         cbind(unique(Year)[2:n],Jacsim[row(Jacsim)-col(Jacsim)==1],
               Hornsim[row(Hornsim)-col(Hornsim)==1],
               Braysim[row(Braysim)-col(Braysim)==1],
               Pearsoncor[row(Pearsoncor)-col(Pearsoncor)==1])
    # added hindcasting 
    simhind[counter2:(counter2+n-2),]<-
          cbind(unique(Year)[1:(n-1)],
                Jacsim[row(Jacsim) %in% 1:(max(row(Jacsim))-1) & 
                       col(Jacsim)==max(col(Jacsim))],
                Hornsim[row(Hornsim)%in%1:(max(row(Hornsim))-1) & 
                      col(Hornsim)==max(col(Hornsim))],
                Braysim[row(Braysim)%in%1:(max(row(Braysim))-1) &
                      col(Braysim)==max(col(Braysim))], 
                Pearsoncor[row(Pearsoncor)%in%1:(max(row(Pearsoncor))-1) & 
                      col(Pearsoncor)==max(col(Pearsoncor))]) 
    counter2<-counter2+n
  }


  baselinesim<-data.frame(unique(Year)[2:n],
       tapply(simbaseline$Jaccard,simbaseline$Year,mean),
       tapply(simbaseline$Horn,simbaseline$Year,mean),
       tapply(simbaseline$Bray,simbaseline$Year,mean),
       tapply(simbaseline$Pearson,simbaseline$Year,mean))
  names(baselinesim)<-c("Year", "Jaccard","Horn","Bray","Pearson")
  nextsim<-data.frame(unique(Year)[2:n],
       tapply(simnext$Jaccard,simnext$Year,mean),
       tapply(simnext$Horn,simnext$Year,mean),
       tapply(simnext$Bray,simnext$Year,mean),
       tapply(simnext$Pearson,simnext$Year,mean))
  names(nextsim)<-c("Year", "Jaccard","Horn","Bray","Pearson")
  hindcastsim<-data.frame(unique(Year)[1:(n-1)],
       tapply(simhind$Jaccard,simhind$Year,mean),
       tapply(simhind$Horn,simhind$Year,mean),
       tapply(simhind$Bray,simhind$Year,mean),
       tapply(simhind$Pearson,simhind$Year,mean))
  names(hindcastsim)<-c("Year", "Jaccard","Horn","Bray","Pearson")
  a<-list(baselinesim,nextsim,hindcastsim)

  return(a)
}
```

**error:**

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, counter2:(counter2 + n - 2), , value = c(NA,  : replacement has 2 items, need 5

***Traceback***

```
6.
stop(sprintf(ngettext(m, "replacement has %d item, need %d", 
    "replacement has %d items, need %d"), m, n * p), domain = NA) 
5.
`[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, counter2:(counter2 + n - 2), , value = structure(c(NA, 
2009), .Dim = 2:1)) 
4.
`[<-`(`*tmp*`, counter2:(counter2 + n - 2), , value = structure(c(NA, 
2009), .Dim = 2:1)) 
3.
myfun(x$Year, x$Bay, x$Species, x$Abundance, 20) 
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.
lapply(summer.split, function(x) myfun(x$Year, x$Bay, 
    x$Species, x$Abundance, 20))
```

Again, the function worked 
Someone seems to have asked a similar question before and was answered by @Marat Talipov but I'm not experienced enough to make sense of what the solution was.

The answer was:

**This error pops up when you're unlucky and i <- runif(n) < 1/2 consists only of FALSE, i.e. no permutations happen. You need to add a check in the swap function to fix this problem.**

[R error in '[<-.data.frame'... replacement has # items, need #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614199/r-error-in-data-frame-replacement-has-items-need)

A subset of my data can be found here:

https://fil.email/sI4Kyhaj

The data was split by "Bay" to generate the list

Note that the function may not throw an error on a different machine because it seems to occur periodically.

Comment: I'm a new user, could you please provide a context for down voting the question?

Comment: I wasn't the downvote, but my guess is because you pasted 70 lines of impenetrable code with no context or data to apply it against. I know I just switch off instantly when I see questions like this with a big block of grey.

Comment: i wasn't the one who downvoted either, but you should simplify your code considerably (this can also help with identifying which line is causing the error), and you need to provide a small subset of your data so we can run this. What sort of troubleshooting steps have you tried? Have you gone through and run each line individually?

Comment: Thanks @RAB. It's all a single function and I wasn't sure how to parse it in a meaningful way. Perhaps I should have provided the traceback from R  studio, which is now included in addition to a link to the subset of my data.

Comment: @user11384727 im not sure what you mean 'parse in a meaningful way'. Just assign each of your function arguments a value (that would otherwise be passed into the function), then line by line go through and run the function and see where the error occurs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The problem is that you've given us a huge block of code, with no example data to test it with, and basically said "debug this for me". Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is located at the peace of code below (and similar indexed reasignment of dataframe's expressions in your code):

```
 simbaseline[counter2:(counter2+n-2),]<-
         cbind(unique(Year)[2:n],Jacsim[2:n],Hornsim[2:n],Braysim[2:n],Pearsoncor[2:n])
```

What happend is that the amount of rows you are trying to assign in the left-hand experession is not equal to the right-hand one. To avoid it you can use intermediate dataframe filled-in with e.g. `NA`s then reassign temporary dataframe to your target data frame. Please see the simulated code below with explanations how it can be done:

```
# simulation
df <- data.frame(i = 1:10, l = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(df)
#   i l
# 1 1 a
# 2 1 1
# 3 a a
# 4 4 d
# 5 5 e
# 6 6 f

# with error
df[1:5, ] <- cbind(1:3, c("a", "b", "c"))
# Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1:5, , value = c("1", "2", "3", "a",  : 
# replacement has 6 items, need 10

# without error
dftemp_in <- cbind(1:3, c("a", "b", "c"))
dftemp_out <- df[1:5, ]
dftemp_out[] <- NA
dftemp_out[seq(nrow(dftemp_in)), ] <- dftemp_in
df[1:5, ] <- dftemp_out
df
# i    l
# 1     1    a
# 2     2    b
# 3     3    c
# 4  <NA> <NA>
# 5  <NA> <NA>
# 6     6    f
# 7     7    g
# 8     8    h
# 9     9    i
# 10   10    j
```